# Get only photos that have 2 users tagged in them (graph API)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to write a graph API query url that will return photos that have the user and their partner tagged in them. I can get the users partner ID from their profile data using the '/me' endpoint however once I have their significant others ID I'm unsure how to proceed or even if its possible.

Ive tried queries like: 
`me?fields=tagged.with(<significant other id>)` and `me/photos/<significant other id>` 
hoping that it would work in the same way as `me/friends/<friend id>` does, but no joy.

Any ideas?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

There can be no global query like "Give me all photos in which Person1 and Person2 are tagged", because the `user_photos` permission is always relative to the user which gave your app the permission to use his data.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/album/photos
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/photo/tags/

A solution could be to

1. Query to the `me` user's and his significant others ids:

   `/me?fields=id,significant_other`
2. Query all the tags from all the `me` user's albums

   `/me/albums?fields=photos{id,tags}`
3. Check in for application if both ids occur in the same tag

As I wrote, you cannot do this for all photos on Facebook, but only for photos of a specific user which gave you permissions.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking something like that, I was hoping I could find a way that didn't involve me parsing all the photos in an album checking the tags and have a bulk query that would return just what i needed. Thanks for the response